# How to use currency symbols code on react native?

Tags: text, react-native, symbols

This is my code

```
setCurrency() {
    switch (this.props.currency) {
        case USD:
            return '&#36;';
        case AMD:
            return '&#1423;';
        case RUB:
            return '&#8381;';
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.rowContent}>
            <Text
                style={styles.fontCurrency}>
                {this.props.text} {this.setCurrency()}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

For the dollar case I get the following. See attached image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aEGd.png)

Comment: Is not really clear what you need, add some more information about your expected result should be

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use existing APIs?

Using them under the hood I would create formatting component for displaying currencies.

Short example here...

```
function getLocale(currency) {
  return {
    usd: "en-US",
    rub: "ru-RU",
  }[currency.toLowerCase()];
}

function Currency({ currency, value }) {
  const locale = getLocale(currency);
  const options = {
    currency,
    locale,
    currencyDisplay: "symbol",
    style: "currency",
  };

  return (
    <Text>
      {Number(value).toLocaleString(locale, options)}
    </Text>
  );
}

// Call it like this
<Currency currency="rub" value={100} />
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible support lacks on Android. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString for detailed info